# I’ve been trying to eliminate flask for a long time but it keeps making this mistake... how can I fix it?

Tags: python

```
  **ERROR: Exception:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 566, in move
        os.rename(src, real_dst)
    PermissionError: [WinError 5] Accesso negato: 'c:\\programdata\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\flask-1.1.1.dist-info\\' -> 'c:\\programdata\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\~=ask-1.1.1.dist-info'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Pasquale\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 188, in _main
        status = self.run(options, args)
      File "C:\Users\Pasquale\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\uninstall.py", line 86, in run
        auto_confirm=options.yes, verbose=self.verbosity > 0,
      File "C:\Users\Pasquale\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 676, in uninstall
        uninstalled_pathset.remove(auto_confirm, verbose)
      File "C:\Users\Pasquale\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_uninstall.py", line 394, in remove
        moved.stash(path)
      File "C:\Users\Pasquale\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_uninstall.py", line 283, in stash
        renames(path, new_path)
      File "C:\Users\Pasquale\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 349, in renames
        shutil.move(old, new)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 578, in move
        rmtree(src)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 516, in rmtree
        return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 400, in _rmtree_unsafe
        onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())`enter code here`
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 398, in _rmtree_unsafe
        os.unlink(fullname)
    PermissionError: [WinError 5] Accesso negato: 'c:\\programdata\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\flask-1.1.1.dist-info\\entry_points.txt'**
```

why i can’t uninstall flask with prompt? I’ve been trying to eliminate flask for a long time but it keeps making this mistake... how can I fix it?

Comment: you have to run your remove commands from an elevated prompt. The error message states "PermissionError".

Comment: can you explain? how i can do it?